# Codeigniter multiple file upload messes file extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, file-io, file-extension

I am trying to get a multiple upload library working for my Codeigniter based website. I have it working almost but I have a slight problem if I upload more than one image, the file extentions get screwed up; for example, if I upload three JPEGS, I get this in my uploads folder,

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg.jpg
image3.jpg.jpg.jpg
```

I cannot see what is causing it, this is the library in question and I am pretty sure that it is in there that the problem is,

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

/**
* This library assumes that you have already loaded the default CI Upload Library seperately
* 
* Functions is based upon CI_Upload, Feel free to modify this 
*   library to function as an extension to CI_Upload
* 
* Library modified by: Alvin Mites
* http://www.mitesdesign.com
* 
*/

class Multi_upload  {
    function Multi_upload () {
//      $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    /**
     * Perform multiple file uploads
     * Based upon JQuery Multiple Upload Class
     * see http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
     */ 
    function go_upload($field = 'userfile') {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['name'][0]))
        {
            $CI->upload->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        } else
        {
            $num_files = count($_FILES[$field]['name']) -1;
            $file_list = array();
            $error_hold = array();
            $error_upload = FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if ( ! $CI->upload->validate_upload_path())
        {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        for ($i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {

//          $fname = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
//          echo "$fname\n\n<br><br>\n\n";

            $error_hold[$i] = FALSE;

            // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
            if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $error = ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['error'][$i])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'][$i];

                switch($error)
                {
                    case 1:  // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_limit';
                        break;
                    case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_form_limit';
                        break;
                    case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_partial';
                        break;
                    case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                    case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_temp_directory';
                        break;
                    case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_unable_to_write_file';
                        break;
                    case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_stopped_by_extension';
                        break;
                    default :
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            // Set the uploaded data as class variables
            $CI->upload->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i];        
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);
            $CI->upload->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'][$i];        
            $CI->upload->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type'][$i]);
            $CI->upload->file_type = strtolower($CI->upload->file_type);
            $CI->upload->file_ext  = $CI->upload->get_extension($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);

            // Convert the file size to kilobytes
            if ($CI->upload->file_size > 0)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_size = round($CI->upload->file_size/1024, 2);
            }

            // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filetype())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filetype';
            }

            // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filesize())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filesize';
            }

            // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
            // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_dimensions())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_dimensions';
            }

            // Sanitize the file name for security
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->clean_file_name($CI->upload->file_name);

            // Remove white spaces in the name
            if ($CI->upload->remove_spaces == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $CI->upload->file_name);
            }

            /*
             * Validate the file name
             * This function appends an number onto the end of
             * the file if one with the same name already exists.
             * If it returns false there was a problem.
             */
            $CI->upload->orig_name = $CI->upload->file_name;

            if ($CI->upload->overwrite == FALSE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->set_filename($CI->upload->upload_path, $CI->upload->file_name);

                if ($CI->upload->file_name === FALSE)
                {
                    $error_hold[$i] = TRUE;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Move the file to the final destination
             * To deal with different server configurations
             * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
             * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
             * reliably work in most environments
             */
            if ( ! @copy($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
            {
                if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
                {
                     $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_destination_error';
                }
            }

            /*
             * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
             * This helps prevent malicious code from being
             * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
             * be disguised as images or other file types.
             */
            if ($CI->upload->xss_clean == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->do_xss_clean();
            }

            if ($error_hold[$i]) {
                $error_upload = TRUE;

//                echo $error_hold[$i];
            } else {
                if ($imageVar = $this->multiple_image_properties($CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name)) {

                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                            'height' => $imageVar->height,
                            'width' => $imageVar->width
                            );
                } else {
                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'type' => $CI->upload->file_type,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            );
                }
            }

// For debugging
/*            
            if (strlen($error_hold[$i]) > 1) {
                    print_r($error_hold);
            }
*/            
        } // end for loop

        // Add error display for individual files        
        if ($error_upload) {
            $this->set_error($error_hold);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $file_list;
        }    
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set Image Properties
     *
     * Uses GD to determine the width/height/type of image
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */    
    function multiple_image_properties($path = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        if ( ! $CI->upload->is_image())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (function_exists('getimagesize'))
        {
            if (FALSE !== ($D = @getimagesize($path)))
            {    
                $types = array(1 => 'gif', 2 => 'jpeg', 3 => 'png');

                $image->width       = $D['0'];
                $image->height      = $D['1'];
                $image->image_type        = ( ! isset($types[$D['2']])) ? 'unknown' : $types[$D['2']];

                return $image;
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set an error message
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */    
    function set_error($msg)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();    
        $CI->lang->load('upload');

        if (is_array($msg))
        {
            foreach ($msg as $val)
            {
                $msg = ($CI->lang->line($val) == FALSE) ? $val : $CI->lang->line($val);                
                $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
                log_message('error', $msg);
            }        
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = ($CI->lang->line($msg) == FALSE) ? $msg : $CI->lang->line($msg);
            $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
            log_message('error', $msg);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this exact problem by amending the Upload.php files located in the library folder.

Comment out line 935:

```
$filename = $this->file_name;
```

Answer (score 17):

Faced the exact similar stuff 2 days ago but did it the old fashioned way hope it helps.
try this ..

```
function tester(){

 $this->load->library('upload');  // NOTE: always load the library outside the loop
 $this->total_count_of_files = count($_FILES['filename']['name'])
 /*Because here we are adding the "$_FILES['userfile']['name']" which increases the count, and for next loop it raises an exception, And also If we have different types of fileuploads */
 for($i=0; $i<$this->total_count_of_files; $i++)
 {

   $_FILES['userfile']['name']    = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $_FILES['filename']['type'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $_FILES['filename']['error'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $_FILES['filename']['size'][$i];

   $config['file_name']     = 'test_'.$i;
   $config['upload_path']   = './public/uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
   $config['max_size']      = '0';
   $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

  $this->upload->initialize($config);

  if($this->upload->do_upload())
  {
    $error += 0;
  }else{
    $error += 1;
  }
 }

 if($error > 0){ return FALSE; }else{ return TRUE; }

}
```

Comment: this had been giving me a headache all morning, I modded your version for myself and it works great!

Comment: This is pretty good. There are some syntax errors, but with a bit of tweaking it works.

replace foreach with for. replace $j with $i

Comment: @JannieT It counts the number of error messages, then at the end if the number of errors are 0 then true is returned, otherwise false is returned.

Comment: @Daniel ummm I was suggesting the code be simplified to  if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
  {
    $error += 1;
  }  without the else

Comment: @JannieT Yeah I see what you mean, depends on your coding style :)

Answer (score 5):

For me it was enough to recall 
`$this->upload->initialize($config);`
every time I called `$this->upload->do_upload()`

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason it was retaining the config data from the previous call to do_upload. Calling initialize() forces it to  update the config data.

Comment: The definitive solution. Thank you @Mihai MATEI.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by your answer thephpx. Won't restructuring $_FILES like that kill off the subarrays once you ahve run it once?

At any rate, I was trying OP's approach by adding the extra index to the a few of the upload library's lines.

I made it work by putting the for loop (over all files) in the upload controller, and the extra index $k as a parameter in the do_upload function in the library.

```
            $this->load->library('upload');
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $k++) {
            $this->upload->initialize($upload); //must reinitialize to get rid of your bug ( i had it as well)
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile',$k)) {
                $this->load->view('upload/image_form', $data + array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors()));
            }
            $udata[$k] = $this->upload->data(); //gradually build up upload->data()
        }
```

Comment: "Won't restructuring $_FILES like that kill off the subarrays once you ahve run it once?"

No. He is only modifying the $_FILES['userfile'] array (not his initial $_FILES['filename'] array. As the do_upload() is being run inside the loop, the $_FILES['userfile'] array being rest every time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get multiple file uploads to work with clux's method but I had to modify the upload class slightly (I'm using Codeigniter 2).  First I created a duplicate of the CI upload class into my applications library.

Line 143:

```
public function do_upload($field = 'userfile')
```

change to

```
public function do_upload($field = 'userfile', $i = 0)
```

And between lines 160 and 200, you must add [$i] to the end of the $_FILES variables.

Example:

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'])
```

change to:

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i])
```

I believe there is a total of 9 of them.

Comment: This will cause problems when you upload a single file.