# Codeigniter & HTML5 - Trying to Upload Multiple Images at Once

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

**View Looks Like This**

```
<?=form_open_multipart('upload/process');?>
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" />
        <?=form_submit('upload', 'Upload');?>
    <?=form_close();?>
```

i want the user to be able to upload multiple images at once. once uploaded i want to make an entry of the image details in the database, and finally move the image to the uploads folder.

i have basic knowledge of codeigniter

ps: i dont want to use uploadify or similar image uploading plugins. trying to keep it as light weight as possible

**Update**
this is the kind of array i am getting when i try var_dump($_FILES['userfile']). what kind of loop should i use to separate the data of the respective images.

```
 array
  'name' => 
    array
      0 => string '01.jpg' (length=6)
      1 => string '1 (26).jpg' (length=10)
  'type' => 
    array
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      1 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array
      0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2AC2.tmp' (length=23)
      1 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2AD3.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => 
    array
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array
      0 => int 409424
      1 => int 260343
```

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: i want to build a basic multiple image uploader using codeigniter without any javascript involved

Comment: I meant what exactly is the problem, what have you tried, etc... But ok, I wrote you the loop you need. See if you can work it out from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this problem aswell. The `$_FILES` data is sent a diffent structure (due to the `multiple=""` attribute) so codeigniter can't handle it. Prepend this before the uploading process:

```
$arr_files  =   @$_FILES['userfile'];

$_FILES     =   array();
foreach(array_keys($arr_files['name']) as $h)
$_FILES["file_{$h}"]    =   array(  'name'      =>  $arr_files['name'][$h],
                                    'type'      =>  $arr_files['type'][$h],
                                    'tmp_name'  =>  $arr_files['tmp_name'][$h],
                                    'error'     =>  $arr_files['error'][$h],
                                    'size'      =>  $arr_files['size'][$h]);
```

Then in the loop function use this:

```
$this->load->library('upload');

$arr_config =   array(  'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png',
                            'upload_path'   =>  'url_path/');

foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h) {

    // Initiate config on upload library etc.

    $this->upload->initialize($arr_config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload($h)) {

        $arr_file_data  =   $this->upload->data();

    }

}
```

**Explanation:**
I simply change the structure of `$_FILES` to the common structure which is sent on a default `<input type="file" />` and the run a loop, fetching all their key names.

Comment: how can i get a var_dump() on the uploaded data before i proceed

Comment: You want information about the $_FILES data or the data which is created upon uploading with Codeigniter?

Comment: problem about the data has been solved. now i just want to the loop i should use to extract the info from the array.(provided in the update)

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're after. I've updated the last code to hopefully make it clearer. You still need to change the structure of your `$_FILES` array before uploading this.

Answer (score 1):

The loop you need:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['name']); $i++){
    if ($_FILES['error'][$i] == 0) {
        //do your stuff here, each image is at $_FILES['tmp_name'][$i]
    }
}
```

Note that is doesn't use the CI upload class, but plain PHP, which I usually find easier to work with instead of the CI's class.

Comment: CI libraries/helpers are raw php but I get what your saying, sometimes its easier and quicker to slap in your own code rather than looking through CI files to see what way they have done a particular function. +1

Comment: Yeah, CI's File Upload class needs to be extended/improved to be more versatile... but it does a great job for the most basic use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this class for multiple file upload https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

This did the trick for me.