# multi image upload wrong quantity on file-upload

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, move

i like to upload some images to a directory with the help of arrays. therefore i have this code:

```
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
            $maxSize = 2097152;
            $Dir = "a/b/c/d";
            $storageDir = "a/b/c/d/tmp_images";

            //Arrays
            $errors2 = $output = array();


            if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){  

            // Validation loop (I prefer for loops for this specific task)
            for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {

                $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
                /*$fileErr = $_FILES['image']['error'][$i];*/
                $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                // Dateiendung überprüfen
                if (!in_array($fileExt, $allowedExtensions)) {
                    $errors2[$fileName][] = "format $fileExt in $fileName is not accepted";
                }

                // check filesize
                if ($fileSize > $maxSize) {
                    $errors2[$fileName][] = "maxsize of 2MB exceeded";
                }


            }

            /*// Handle validation errors here
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                echo "Fehler beim Upload des Bildmaterials:"; 
                echo ($errors); ->gibt "Array" aus
            }*/


            if (is_dir($Dir)){
                mkdir($storageDir, 0755);
            }else{
                mkdir($Dir, 0755);
                mkdir($storageDir, 0755);
            }


            // Fileupload
            for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {

            // Get base info
            $fileBase = basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $fileExt = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];

            // Construct destination path
            $fileDst = $storageDir.'/'.basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
            for ($j = 0; file_exists($fileDst); $j++) {
                $fileDst = "$storageDir/$fileName-$j.$fileExt";
            }

            // Move the file 

            if (count($errors2) == 0) { 
                if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
                                    ...
                                }
                        }
```

the problem with that code is the following: in case of uploading two or more files with an accepted ending it will echo out:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to access abc2.png in /a/b/xxx.php on line xxx
```

which refers to that line:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
```

this message will be shown for each picture except the first one. so i have no clue what i do wrong. i would really appreciate if there is someone who could help me out. i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very `similar` to my answer at [limiting the checking condition while uploading swf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151960/limiting-the-checking-condition-while-uploading-swf-files/10152156#10152156)

This is how you should implement such ..

**FULL Script**

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
$allowedExtensions = array (
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'bmp',
        'tiff',
        'gif' 
);
$maxSize = 2097152;
$dirImage = "photos/tmp_images";
$errors = $output = array ();
if (isset ( $_FILES ['image'] )) {
    foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {

        $fileName = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key];
        $fileSize = $_FILES ['image'] ['size'] [$key];
        $fileTemp = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] [$key];

        $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

        if (empty ( $fileName ))
            continue;

            // Dateiendung Ã¼berprÃ¼fen
        if (! in_array ( $fileExt, $allowedExtensions )) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = "format $fileExt in $fileName is not accepted";
        }

        if ($fileSize > $maxSize) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = "maxsize of 2MB exceeded";
        }

        if (! mkdir_recursive ( $dirImage, 0777 )) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = "Error  Creating /Writing  Directory $dirImage ";
        }

        // Construct destination path
        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        $filePrifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExt );
        $i = 0;
        while ( file_exists ( $fileDst ) ) {
            $i ++;
            $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePrifix . "_" . $i . "." . $fileExt;

        }
        // Move the file

        if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
            if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                // ...

                $output [$fileName] = "OK";
            }
        }

    }
}

function mkdir_recursive($pathname, $mode) {
    is_dir ( dirname ( $pathname ) ) || mkdir_recursive ( dirname ( $pathname ), $mode );
    return is_dir ( $pathname ) || mkdir ( $pathname, $mode );
}
if (! empty ( $errors )) {
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ( $errors as $file => $error ) {
        echo $file, PHP_EOL;
        echo "==============", PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $error as $line ) {
            echo $line, PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}

if (! empty ( $output )) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Uploaded Files", PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $output as $file => $status ) {
        echo $file, "=", $status, PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "</pre>";
}
?>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename 1:</label> <input type="file" name="image[]"
        id="file" /> <br /> <label for="file">Filename 2:</label> <input
        type="file" name="image[]" id="file" /> <br /> <label for="file">Filename
        3:</label> <input type="file" name="image[]" id="file" /> <br /> <input
        type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: all you need to do is update the question rather than create another one ... @bonny

Comment: It not growing because you accepted an answer without indicating you still have problems ... when you edit and add new information everyone would be aware and see what they can do till the issue is resolved ....

Comment: the function is suppose to be in the same page ..... .... I would edit it so that you can understand how to use it ...

Comment: save it as `test.php` run it and paste here the exact error or output you get ...

Comment: I think i know you are having problems ...  `PHP SAVE MODE` 1. You don't have to create folder in that path `a/b/c/d/tmp_image` 2. if you have access to `php.ini` set `safe_mode = Off` or you can use `.htaccess` and put this there `php_value safe_mode "1"` .. you should have a working script ...

Comment: It uploaded one .. because that is the only one with valid extension add var_dump( $errors) to the `php code` .. you would see the errors  ..

Comment: change `runDir ( $dirImage )` to  `runDir ( $dirImage ,0777 );` delete the first folder and run it again ....

Comment: Can you see that your directory `path` are totally wrong ???? user proper full path

Comment: your path should be something like `"/public_html/www/a/b/c/"` not with `ftp` ..... and make sure you have right to that folder or just create it first before you run your script

Comment: understanding system path are basic in any programming ... it would only create dir it has access to  ... and has right ... and also i don't see any sense in create temp dir all the time  ..... are you doing thin on a remote or local server ???

Comment: your move is not working because you where using `for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);` that is why i rewrote the script ....  now use my script and set the upload dir to `/var/www/web775/html/a/b/c/d`

Comment: ok still using my script try `a/b/c/d` as the path ... and give me the exact error don't forget to change `runDir ( $dirImage )` to `runDir ( $dirImage ,0777 );`

Comment: am tried of repeating the same thing all over .. told if if you want to see the errors `var_dump($errors)`  .... I can't help if you can not perform basic task ... and i have to repeat everything

Comment: change `chmod` of current directory to 0777 or create the first folder `a` and set the `chmod` to 0777 .... if this does not give you permission .. then there is something you are doing wrong and am not understanding ... .. I just tested this script on my server and it works perfectly fine ...

Comment: Really form the end .. i can really do much .... you need to get someone to do that for you .. or if you have `cpanel` create subdomain with FTP restricted to that folder .. i can upload and configure form there .. then you can remove the `ftp` login details later ....

Comment: get some you can give your server access to to help you do it .... except you can create a temporary access for me to help you do it

Comment: send it to `h556683@rppkn.com` it mail box would be deleted in 10sec ''i used `http://10minutemail.com`

Comment: It was too late resend it to h557791@rppkn.com .. not i must get it before the next 5mins

Comment: Still waiting for your mail at `h557791@rppkn.com` the mail would expire in another 10 mins

Comment: Not yet .. am still waiting for it

Comment: I did not get it  .. ok try `hcyuyixt@sharklasers.com` .... you take too long before you respond ...

Comment: You have a perfectly working code now ... its created multiple directory automatically .. gives error information and output information .... I guess have tried ... Its not a new code .. i just formatted and removed some things you don't need. Have a wonderful day

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fBkj2Jaq .... i hope you don't more request on this because you are already taking it like a support chat

Comment: okay, i will close it now. thank you very much for professional help. i really appreciate. have a nice day. best wishes

Answer (score 2):

First of, I would name the uploaded fields seperatly. E.g. name the first field `<input name="image_1" type="file" />` and the second `<input name="image_2" type="file" />`. Then you can iterate over the `$_FILES` array instead:

```
foreach($_FILES as $fileId => $file){
    //make sure it's a file you want (optional)
    if(!preg_match("/^image\_\d+$/",$fileId){
         continue;
    }

    //the rest of your code from the for loop
}
```

Secondly, you need to make sure that your form's enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

Does any of this help?

Comment: He's using HTML5 `<input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" />`, so he gets them in that format.

Comment: hello and thanks or answering. the problem is that i can't easily name every field because this input field is beeing created by a function.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you accessing the `$_FILES` superglobal array as a three dimensional array?

if you want the file name of the file uploaded from an `<input type="file" name="image"/>` all you have to do is `$name = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'name' ]` there is no need for the `[ $i ]` at the end.

You need to loop over the entries in $_FILES like this:

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $inputName => $fileData )
{
    // $inputName is be 'image` for the first input and so on,
    // $fileData will be an array of the attributes [ 'name', 'tmp_name', ... ]
}
```

Comment: He's using HTML5 `<input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" />`, so he gets them in that format.

Comment: i use that because of the explicit error messages that i like to show for each file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this may solve it for you, but you can try to convert these into "normal" `$_FILES` values.

```
$arr_files  =   @$_FILES['image'];

$_FILES     =   array();
foreach(array_keys($arr_files['name']) as $h)
$_FILES["image_{$h}"]    =   array(  'name'      =>  $arr_files['name'][$h],
                                    'type'      =>  $arr_files['type'][$h],
                                    'tmp_name'  =>  $arr_files['tmp_name'][$h],
                                    'error'     =>  $arr_files['error'][$h],
                                    'size'      =>  $arr_files['size'][$h]);
```

And then run the loop like normal.

[See previous related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903619/codeigniter-html5-trying-to-upload-multiple-images-at-once/9903681#9903681)