# Multi upload image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want multi-upload image by codeigniter and use from following libraries, my problem is here that after select several (multi) image it give me in output (php) just a image, for example:

If i selected multi image as:

> image1.gif  |  image2.gif  |  image3.gif

It just uploading :

> image3.gif

In the meantime I am using the control function ‍‍`foreach` for upload image and it's no problem.

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" >

<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Multi_upload
{
    function Multi_upload()
    {
        //      $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function go_upload($field = 'userfile')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if (!isset($_FILES[$field]['name'][0])) {
            $CI->upload->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $num_files    = count($_FILES[$field]['name']) - 1;
            $file_list    = array();
            $error_hold   = array();
            $error_upload = FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if (!$CI->upload->validate_upload_path()) {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {
            //            $fname = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
            //            echo "$fname\n\n<br><br>\n\n";

            $error_hold[$i] = FALSE;

            // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
            if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i])) {
                $error = (!isset($_FILES[$field]['error'][$i])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'][$i];

                switch ($error) {
                    case 1: // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_limit';
                        break;
                    case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_form_limit';
                        break;
                    case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_partial';
                        break;
                    case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                    case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_temp_directory';
                        break;
                    case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_unable_to_write_file';
                        break;
                    case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_stopped_by_extension';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            // Set the uploaded data as class variables
            $CI->upload->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i];
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->file_name = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
            $CI->upload->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'][$i];
            $CI->upload->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type'][$i]);
            $CI->upload->file_type = strtolower($CI->upload->file_type);
            $CI->upload->file_ext  = $CI->upload->get_extension($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);

            // Convert the file size to kilobytes
            if ($CI->upload->file_size > 0) {
                $CI->upload->file_size = round($CI->upload->file_size / 1024, 2);
            }

            // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
            if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_filetype()) {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filetype';
            }

            // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
            if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_filesize()) {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filesize';
            }

            // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
            // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
            if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_dimensions()) {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_dimensions';
            }

            // Sanitize the file name for security
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->clean_file_name($CI->upload->file_name);

            // Remove white spaces in the name
            if ($CI->upload->remove_spaces == TRUE) {
                $CI->upload->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $CI->upload->file_name);
            }

            /*
             * Validate the file name
             * This function appends an number onto the end of
             * the file if one with the same name already exists.
             * If it returns false there was a problem.
             */
            $CI->upload->orig_name = $CI->upload->file_name;

            if ($CI->upload->overwrite == FALSE) {
                $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->set_filename($CI->upload->upload_path, $CI->upload->file_name);

                if ($CI->upload->file_name === FALSE) {
                    $error_hold[$i] = TRUE;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Move the file to the final destination
             * To deal with different server configurations
             * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
             * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
             * reliably work in most environments
             */
            if (!@copy($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
                if (!@move_uploaded_file($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_destination_error';
                }
            }

            /*
             * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
             * This helps prevent malicious code from being
             * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
             * be disguised as images or other file types.
             */
            if ($CI->upload->xss_clean == TRUE) {
                $CI->upload->do_xss_clean();
            }

            if ($error_hold[$i]) {
                $error_upload = TRUE;

                //                echo $error_hold[$i];
            } else {
                if ($imageVar = $this->multiple_image_properties($CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
                    $file_list[] = array(
                        'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                        'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name,
                        'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                        'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                        'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                        'height' => $imageVar->height,
                        'width' => $imageVar->width
                    );
                } else {
                    $file_list[] = array(
                        'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                        'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name,
                        'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                        'type' => $CI->upload->file_type,
                        'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext
                    );
                }
            }

            // For debugging


            //if (strlen($error_hold[$i]) > 1) {
            //print_r($error_hold);
            //}

        } // end for loop

        // Add error display for individual files        
        if ($error_upload) {
            $this->set_error($error_hold);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $file_list;
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set Image Properties
     *
     * Uses GD to determine the width/height/type of image
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */
    function multiple_image_properties($path = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if (!$CI->upload->is_image()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (function_exists('getimagesize')) {
            if (FALSE !== ($D = @getimagesize($path))) {
                $types = array(
                    1 => 'gif',
                    2 => 'jpeg',
                    3 => 'png'
                );

                $image->width      = $D['0'];
                $image->height     = $D['1'];
                $image->image_type = (!isset($types[$D['2']])) ? 'unknown' : $types[$D['2']];

                return $image;
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set an error message
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */
    function set_error($msg)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->lang->load('upload');

        if (is_array($msg)) {
            foreach ($msg as $val) {
                $msg               = ($CI->lang->line($val) == FALSE) ? $val : $CI->lang->line($val);
                $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
                log_message('error', $msg);
            }
        } else {
            $msg               = ($CI->lang->line($msg) == FALSE) ? $msg : $CI->lang->line($msg);
            $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
            log_message('error', $msg);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
}
?>
```

How do we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neat approach which wouldn't require any extra library would be [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903619/codeigniter-html5-trying-to-upload-multiple-images-at-once/9903681#9903681) together with the `multiple=""` attribute.

Don't underestimate the comfort of selecting multiple files at once through UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code below i think you want this.

Each time you want to upload a new file you need to initialize configuration for each file to **$this->upload->initialize($config);**

```
// Has the form been posted?
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Load the library - no config specified here
    $this->load->library('upload');

    // Check if there was a file uploaded - there are other ways to
    // check this such as checking the 'error' for the file - if error
    // is 0, you are good to code
    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
    {
        // Specify configuration for File 1
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';      

        // Initialize config for File 1
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        // Upload file 1
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

    }

    // Do we have a second file?
    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile1']['name']))
    {
        // Config for File 2 - can be completely different to file 1's config
        // or if you want to stick with config for file 1, do nothing!
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/dir2/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        // Initialize the new config
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        // Upload the second file
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

    }
}
else
{
    $this->load->view("upload_form");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also try this amazing library for multi upload functionality. Amazing interface and fast performance.

http://www.plupload.com/