# Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0

Tags: arrays, file, codeigniter, upload

I've been searching and struggling for 3 days now to make this works but I just can't.
What I want to do is use a Multiple file input form and then upload them. I can't just use a fixed number of file to upload. I tried many many solutions on StackOverflow but I wasn't able to find a working one.

Here's my Upload controller

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','html'));
}

function index()
{    
    $this->load->view('pages/uploadform', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './Images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';


    $this->load->library('upload');

 foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key => $value)
    {

        if( ! empty($key['name']))
        {

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $error['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

                $this->load->view('pages/uploadform', $error);
            }    
            else
            {
                $data[$key] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('pages/uploadsuccess', $data[$key]);


            }
         }

    }    
  }    
 }
 ?>
```

My upload form is This.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" multiple name="userfile[]" size="20" />
<br /><br />


<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I just keep having this error :

> You did not select a file to upload.

Here's the array of the example:

> Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => youtube.png [1] => zergling.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => E:\wamp\tmp\php7AC2.tmp [1] => E:\wamp\tmp\php7AC3.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 35266 [1] => 186448 ) ) )

I have this like 5 times in a row if I select 2 files.
I also use the standard Upload library.

Comment: I honestly find it hard to believe that `$key` is actually an array inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: `foreach( $_FILES as $file ){ //do_upload( $file ) }`

Comment: @KemalFadillah it is actually. Gorelative, it doesn't work i get  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in the upload library file

Comment: @CinetiK if `$key` is really an array like you said, then it doesn't make any sense to pass it as an argument when you call `do_upload()`. Because the function expects one parameter that is a string.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code, Image is not moving to given folder

Comment: Did you try the solution below ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work with your help!

Here's my code:

```
 function do_upload()
{       
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
    }
}

private function set_upload_options()
{   
    //upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './Images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: CinetiK, if our help was useful (you have found the solution through my answer) you must mark our answer is useful!! The solution is in my answer!!

Comment: Works for me. is there any way to make a table of all the selected files?

Comment: For that purpose I would recommend you to check how to upload files with jQuery/Ajax (also check http://www.grocerycrud.com/image-crud)

Comment: This code is also the only way I can get it to work. However it's so ugly that one need to convert the array values... Should be a more beautiful solution! Possibly extending the ul library?

Comment: @jtheman Yes it's not beautiful coding I agree but that's the only solution I could find at that time and I managed to use it with Ajax upload so the app could display files while there were being uploaded.

Comment: thanks dude, its working, I edit this code to $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

Comment: Working in 3.0 too!

Answer (score 4):

You should use this library for multi upload in CI https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Installation Simply copy the MY_Upload.php file to your applications library directory.

Use: function test_up in controller

```
public function test_up(){
if($this->input->post('submit')){
    $path = './public/test_upload/';
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "upload_path"=>$path,
        "allowed_types"=>"*"
    ));
    if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("myfile")){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}else{
    $this->load->view('test/upload_view');
}
```

}

upload_view.php in applications/view/test folder

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="myfile" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: having problem with this method. something wrong in the `do_multi_upload` function. doesnt return anything. blank screen error

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

It's working fine for me

You must initialize each time the library

```
    function do_upload()
    {
        foreach ($_FILES as $index => $value)
        {
            if ($value['name'] != '')
            {
                $this->load->library('upload');
                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());

                //upload the image
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($index))
                {
                    $error['upload_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors("<span class='error'>", "</span>");
                    
                    //load the view and the layout
                    $this->load->view('pages/uploadform', $error);

                    return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    
                     $data[$key] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                     $this->load->view('pages/uploadsuccess', $data[$key]);

       
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private function set_upload_options()
    {   
        //upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'your upload path';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        
        return $config;
    }
```

**Further edit**

I have found the way you must upload your files with one unique input box

> CodeIgniter doesn't support multiple files. Using the do_upload() in a foreach won't be different than using it outside.
>
> You will need to deal with it without the help of CodeIgniter. Here's an example https://github.com/woxxy/FoOlSlide/blob/master/application/controllers/admin/series.php#L331-370
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9846065/1171049

This is that  said you in the commments :)

Comment: it still doesn't work for me. With your function and my view (quoted above) i get
> is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
in the library file Upload.php (line 161)
I change the upload path of course. And it still tell me 
> no file selected

Comment: I found the problem, you need another interation on the foreach, because the format of $_FILES when uses a multiple upload input is different. For example: [name] => Array ( [0] => youtube.png [1] => zergling.jpg ). Is not a array of arrays is one array with the properties as array

Comment: So i need a function to sort of modify my "array" into a good one and then it will work right ?

Answer (score 1):

another bit of code here:

refer: https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos Rincones suggested; don't be affraid of playing with superglobals.

```
$files = $_FILES;

for($i=0; $i<count($files['userfile']['name']); $i++)
{
    $_FILES = array();
    foreach( $files['userfile'] as $k=>$v )
    {
        $_FILES['userfile'][$k] = $v[$i];                
    }

    $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your smart code. your code is working well in my project. How to get file name for multiple images for your code. Waiting for your reply.  Is this possible this way $this->upload->data('userfile');. I have tried this way but no sucess.   Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

All Posted files will be come in $_FILES variable, for use codeigniter upload library we need to give field_name that we are using in for upload (by default it will be 'userfile'), so we get all posted file and create another files array that create our own name for each files, and give this name to codeigniter library do_upload function.

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $j = 1;                 
    foreach($_FILES as $filekey=>$fileattachments){
        foreach($fileattachments as $key=>$val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                $i = 1;
                foreach($val as $v){
                    $field_name = "multiple_".$filekey."_".$i;
                    $_FILES[$field_name][$key] = $v;
                    $i++;   
                }
            }else{
                $field_name = "single_".$filekey."_".$j;
                $_FILES[$field_name] = $fileattachments;
                $j++;
                break;
            }
        }                       
        // Unset the useless one 
        unset($_FILES[$filekey]);
    }
    foreach($_FILES as $field_name => $file){
        if(isset($file['error']) && $file['error']==0){
            $config['upload_path'] = [upload_path];
            $config['allowed_types'] = [allowed_types];
            $config['max_size'] = 100;
            $config['max_width'] = 1024;
            $config['max_height'] = 768;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)){
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                echo "Error Message : ". $error['error'];
            }else{
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                echo "Uploaded FileName : ".$data['file_name'];
                // Code for insert into database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function imageupload() 
    {

      $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp';
  $config['max_size']   = '0';
  $config['max_width']  = '0';
  $config['max_height']  = '0';

  $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
  $config['width'] = 50;
  $config['height'] = 50;

  foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
  { 
     for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)
     {
     $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
     $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
     $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s]; 
     $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
     $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
         {
           $data['userfile'][$i] = $this->upload->data();
       $full_path = $data['userfile']['full_path'];


           $config['source_image'] = $full_path;
           $config['new_image'] = './uploads/resiezedImage';

           $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
           $this->image_lib->resize(); 
           $this->image_lib->clear();

         }
         else
         {
           $data['upload_errors'][$i] = $this->upload->display_errors();
         } 
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code in my custom library 
call that from my controller like below,

```
function __construct() {<br />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; parent::__construct();<br />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   $this->load->library('CommonMethods');<br />
}<br />

$config = array();<br />
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/upload/images/';<br />
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';<br />
$config['max_width'] = 150;<br />
$config['max_height'] = 150;<br />
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;<br />
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;<br />

// upload multiplefiles<br />
$fileUploadResponse = $this->commonmethods->do_upload_multiple_files('profile_picture', $config);
```

---

```
/**
 * do_upload_multiple_files - Multiple Methods
 * @param type $fieldName
 * @param type $options
 * @return type
 */
public function do_upload_multiple_files($fieldName, $options) {

    $response = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES[$fieldName]['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES[$fieldName]['name']= $files[$fieldName]['name'][$i];
        $_FILES[$fieldName]['type']= $files[$fieldName]['type'][$i];
        $_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name']= $files[$fieldName]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES[$fieldName]['error']= $files[$fieldName]['error'][$i];
        $_FILES[$fieldName]['size']= $files[$fieldName]['size'][$i];    

        $this->CI->load->library('upload');
        $this->CI->upload->initialize($options);

        //upload the image
        if (!$this->CI->upload->do_upload($fieldName)) {
            $response['erros'][] = $this->CI->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
            $response['result'][] = $this->CI->upload->data();
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('submit'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="userfile"  multiple="" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

MODEL : FilesUpload

```
class FilesUpload extends CI_Model {

    public function setFiles()
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
            for ($s = 0; $s <= $count - 1; $s++) {
                $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];

                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/product/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '10000000';
                $config['max_width'] = '51024';
                $config['max_height'] = '5768';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $data_error = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    var_dump($data_error);
                } else {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                }
                $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
            }

        $names = implode(',', $name_array);

        return $names;
    }
}
```

CONTROLER submit

```
class Submit extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('html', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
        $this->load->model('FilesUpload');

        $data = $this->FilesUpload->setFiles();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Change $_FILES to new vars and loop them
        foreach($_FILES['files'] as $key=>$val)
        {
            $i = 1;
            foreach($val as $v)
            {
                $field_name = "file_".$i;
                $_FILES[$field_name][$key] = $v;
                $i++;   
            }
        }
        // Unset the useless one ;)
        unset($_FILES['files']);

        // Put each errors and upload data to an array
        $error = array();
        $success = array();

        // main action to upload each file
        foreach($_FILES as $field_name => $file)
        {
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
            {
                echo ' failed ';
            }else{
                echo ' success ';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageUpload(){
            if ($this->input->post('submitImg') && !empty($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
                $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
                $userID = $this->session->userdata('userID');
                $this->load->library('upload');

                $config['upload_path'] = './userdp/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size'] = '9184928';
                $config['max_width']  = '5000';
                $config['max_height']  = '5000';

                $files = $_FILES;
                $cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

                for($i = 0 ; $i < $cpt ; $i++){
                    $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    

                    $imageName = 'image_'.$userID.'_'.rand().'.png';

                    $config['file_name'] = $imageName;

                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if($this->upload->do_upload('files')){
                        $fileData = $this->upload->data(); //it return
                        $uploadData[$i]['picturePath'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($uploadData)) {
                    $imgInsert = $this->insert_model->insertImg($uploadData);
                    $statusMsg = $imgInsert?'Files uploaded successfully.':'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$statusMsg);
                    redirect('home/user_dash');
                }
            }
            else{
                redirect('home/user_dash');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined method available in codeigniter to upload multiple file at one time but you can send file in array and upload them one by one

here is refer: Here is best option to upload multiple file in codeigniter 3.0.1 with preview https://codeaskbuzz.com/how-to-upload-multiple-file-in-codeigniter-framework/

Answer (score 0):

SO what I change is I load upload library each time

```
                $config = array();
                $config['upload_path'] = $filePath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']      = '0';
                $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

                $files = $_FILES;
                $count = count($_FILES['nameUpload']['name']);


                for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
                {
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    $_FILES['nameUpload']['name']= $files['nameUpload']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['nameUpload']['type']= $files['nameUpload']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['nameUpload']['tmp_name']= $files['nameUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['nameUpload']['error']= $files['nameUpload']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['nameUpload']['size']= $files['nameUpload']['size'][$i];

                    $this->upload->do_upload('nameUpload');
                }
```

And it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter 3

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/TestingController/insertdata') ?>" method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">File</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="files" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>


public function insertdatanew()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['filesdua']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
        $_FILES['filesdua']['name'] = $files['filesdua']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['filesdua']['type'] = $files['filesdua']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['filesdua']['tmp_name'] = $files['filesdua']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['filesdua']['error'] = $files['filesdua']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['filesdua']['size'] = $files['filesdua']['size'][$i];

        // fungsi uploud
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/testing/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = '*';
        $config['max_size']             = 0;
        $config['max_width']            = 0;
        $config['max_height']           = 0;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filesdua')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);

            // $this->load->view('welcome_message', $error);
        } else {

            // menambil nilai value yang di upload  
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $nilai = $data['upload_data']; 
            $filename = $nilai['file_name'];
            var_dump($filename);

            // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
    // var_dump($cpt);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently work on it. Try this function:

```
/**
 * @return array an array of your files uploaded.
 */
private function _upload_files($field='userfile'){
    $files = array();
    foreach( $_FILES[$field] as $key => $all )
        foreach( $all as $i => $val )
            $files[$i][$key] = $val;

    $files_uploaded = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) { 
        $_FILES[$field] = $files[$i];
        if ($this->upload->do_upload($field))
            $files_uploaded[$i] = $this->upload->data($files);
        else
            $files_uploaded[$i] = null;
    }
    return $files_uploaded;
}
```

in your case:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="images[]" size="20" />
```

or

```
<input type="file" name="images[]">
<input type="file" name="images[]">
<input type="file" name="images[]">
```

in the controller:

```
public function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './Images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    //...

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if ($_FILES['images']) {
        $images= $this->_upload_files('images');
        print_r($images);
    }
}
```

Some basic reference from PHP manual: [PHP file upload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Answer (score -1):

Save, then redefine the variable $_FILES to whatever you need.
maybe not the best solution, but this worked for me.

```
function do_upload()
{

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());

    $quantFiles = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);


    for($i = 0; $i < $quantFiles ; $i++)
    {
        $arquivo[$i] = array
                    (
                        'userfile' => array 
                                        (
                                            'name' => $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i],
                                            'type' => $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i],
                                            'tmp_name' => $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],
                                            'error' => $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i],
                                            'size' => $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i]
                                        )
                    );
    }


    for($i = 0; $i < $quantFiles ; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES = '';
        $_FILES = $arquivo[$i];



        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error[$i] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());


            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {

            $data[$i] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            var_dump($this->upload->data());
        }


    }





    if(isset($error))
        {
            $this->index($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index($data);
        }
```

}

the separate function to establish the config..

```
private function set_upload_options()
{   
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xml|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';

    return $config;
}
```