# How to upload multiple images using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am able to upload & insert a image ine the database. But I am unable to upload multiple images, what should I change in the below code , in order to upload multiple images

My form.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/addproduct'); ?> 
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:60%;"> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Product name </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_input($fpname) ?>  </td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Price </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_input($fprice) ?>  </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Image 1: </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_upload("userfile"); ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Image 2: </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_upload("img2"); ?>    </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;">Image 3:  </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_upload("img3"); ?>    </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Details </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><?php echo form_textarea($fdetails) ?>  </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td> 
            </tr> 
        </table>  
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

controller.php

```
      function addproduct() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1879800';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '2768';
  $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>')->set_rules('pname', 'Product Name', 'trim|min_length[4]|required|max_length[112]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>')->set_rules('details', 'Details', 'trim|min_length[4]|required|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>')->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|min_length[4]|required|max_length[112]|numeric');

        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {//--false
            $data = $this->productmodel->productdetails();
            $this->load->view('admin/home', $data);
        }

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {  // no file uploaded or failed upload
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $data = $this->productmodel->productdetails();
            print_r($error);
            $this->load->view('admin/home', $data);
        } 
        else 
        {  
            $data =$this->upload->data();
            $this->productmodel->entry_insert_productdetails($data["file_name"]); 
            $data = $this->productmodel->productdetails();
              $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'One record added successfully...'); 
              redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/index');
        }
    }
```

**Update**:
Source code generated from the form

```
 <form action="http://localhost/wclick/index.php/admin/addproduct" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:60%;"> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Product name </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><input type="text" name="pname" value="" maxlength="190" size="20"  />  </td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Price </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><input type="text" name="price" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" placeholder=" " id="txtsubject"  />  </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Image 1: </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><input type="file" name="userfile" value=""  /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Image 2: </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><input type="file" name="img2" value=""  />    </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;">Image 3:  </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><input type="file" name="img3" value=""  />    </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: right;"> Details </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;"><textarea name="details" cols="20" rows="4" ></textarea>  </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;width:50%;text-align: center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td> 
            </tr> 
        </table>  
      </form>
```

Comment: Show us source code of form_input() and form_open_multipart('admin/addproduct');

Comment: @ZalonisAntonis I updated my question above. Please check

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0)

Comment: @Anonymous2011 who ever linked this question is not exactly with the link. Kindly follow read my question once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call below function every time before do_upload

```
$this->upload->initialize($upload);
```

Assume all files in this array

$_FILES['userfile']['name']
then your script would look like

```
        $this->load->library('upload');
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $k++) {
        $this->upload->initialize($upload); //must reinitialize to get rid of your bug ( i had it as well)
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile',$k)) {
            $this->load->view('upload/image_form', $data + array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors()));
        }
        $udata[$k] = $this->upload->data(); //gradually build up upload->data()
    }
```

Comment: did you saw there i have diffrent file name & how can i send them to store it once, You are teching me like one by one format

Comment: @rani Try to understand, I said add $this->upload->initialize($upload); this before every do_upload function call. I wrote here sample code according to that I need array of files for multiple file upload.

Comment: okay then how can i send those files to save in my database? Like i have `four` database column in my table , how can i send them to upload in my database table?

Comment: not solved still, how to send each img name to save into database?

Comment: now after so many days i solved this answer. Can u plz vote up my above question because its -1 voting

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the CI manual you have to provide the field name for the upload.

```
$field_name = "some_field_name";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name);
```

you will need to do this for each of the different files you want to update, perhaps in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following links, as they may help you:

[Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0)

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234635/#1051511