# change the input name at multiple upload form codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I try to change the 'userfile' name as input name in form, from the theard [Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0) as the best answers for the question, and it doesn't work.

```
function do_upload()
{
$this->load->library('upload');
$files = $_FILES;
$cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{

    $_FILES['imageoption']['name']= $files['imageoption']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['imageoption']['type']= $files['imageoption']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['imageoption']['tmp_name']= $files['imageoption']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['imageoption']['error']= $files['imageoption']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['imageoption']['size']= $files['imageoption']['size'][$i];    



$this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
$this->upload->do_upload();


  }
}
private function set_upload_options()
{
//  upload an image options
  $config = array();
  $config['upload_path'] = './Images/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size']      = '0';
  $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
  return $config;
}
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<?php echo $errors;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('tryout/guru/do_upload');?>
<div id="Question1">
Image Question       
  <input type="file" name="imagequestion[]" size="20"  />
Image Option
  <input type="file" name="imageoption[]" size="20"  />
  <input type="file" name="imageoption[]" size="20"  />
</div>
<div id="Question2">
Image Question       
  <input type="file" name="imagequestion[]" size="20"  />
Image Option
  <input type="file" name="imageoption[]" size="20"  />
  <input type="file" name="imageoption[]" size="20"  />
</div>

  <br /><br />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

I want to make multiple upload with different name for the `imagequestion` and `imageoption` at once submit. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing it here too:

```
$cpt = count($_FILES['imageoption']['name']);
```

Right now $i is equal to $cpt since $cpt is returning 0. So your for loop ends before it begins.

Also make sure that your input has:

```
"multiple name ='imageoption[]'"
```

I see that you are echoing $errors... is that displaying anything at all? Make sure you are passing your errors to your view just like in the link:

```
$error['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

$this->load->view('pages/uploadform', $error);
```

It's always best to edit your first answer rather than posting a new answer to really ask the same question.

Comment: Can you edit your original comment to post up your actual form? Also, are you sure you have write permissions in Images?