# Multiple files upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I want to upload multiple files using single element. So I try this example.

[Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0)

This is my form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="jNice" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://xxxx.dev/admin/add_estates">              
    <fieldset>      
            <label>Title * : </label>                       
            <input type="text" class="text-long" value="" name="title">

            <label>Description : </label>                       
            <textarea class="mceEditor" rows="10" cols="40" name="description"></textarea>

            <label>Image : </label>                     
            <input type="file" multiple="" name="images[]">                             

            <button class="button-submit" type="submit" name="save" id="">Save</button>
    </fieldset>         
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
public function add_estates()
{
    $data['page_title'] = "&copy; IDEAL - Administrator - Real State - Add Real Estate";
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/add_estates';

    if ($this->input->post() !== FALSE) {           
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Career Title', 'trim|required');           

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {                

            $title = $this->input->post('title');
            $description = $this->input->post('description');

            if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0])) {
                if ($this->upload_files($title, $_FILES['images']) === FALSE) {
                    $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
                }
            }                   

            if (!isset($data['error'])) {
                $this->admin_model->add_estate($title, $description, $image_name);    
                $this->session->set_flashdata('suc_msg', 'New real estate added successfully'); 
                redirect('admin/add_estates');    
            }          
        }
    }

    $data['suc_msg'] = $this->session->flashdata('suc_msg');

    $this->load->view('layout_admin', $data);
}
```

This is my file upload method

```
private function upload_files($title, $files)
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => './upload/real_estate/',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
        'overwrite'     => 1,                       
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
        $_FILES['images']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['images']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['images']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

        $config['file_name'] = $title .'_'. $image;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload($image)) {
            $this->upload->data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But it give `You did not select a file to upload.` every time. What is the issue?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post

Comment: if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) // try this

Comment: your codes are working now?

Comment: I have added one solution in above link.
Refer for solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0/38203150#38203150

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I change upload method with `images[]` according to @Denmark.

```
    private function upload_files($path, $title, $files)
    {
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'   => $path,
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
            'overwrite'     => 1,                       
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $images = array();

        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
            $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

            $fileName = $title .'_'. $image;

            $images[] = $fileName;

            $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) {
                $this->upload->data();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

Comment: ok , what kind of file is .fr3 files? pdf is application, html is text, fr3 is?

Comment: .fr3 = FastReport template file?

Comment: Where .fr3 is mentioned here?

Comment: Error: Undefined index: name after the line foreach... What do do?

Comment: $_FILES is one of PHP's built in $GLOBALS. You definitely should not be assigning anything to it ever. This is very bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

You should use this library for multi upload in CI
https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Answer (score 4):

```
public function index() {

    $user = $this->session->userdata("username");
    $file_path = "./images/" . $user . '/';

    if (isset($_FILES['multipleUpload'])) {

        if (!is_dir('images/' . $user)) {
            mkdir('./images/' . $user, 0777, TRUE);
        }

        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i ++) {

            $name = time().$files ['multipleUpload'] ['name'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['name'] = $name;
            $_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['type'] = $files ['multipleUpload'] ['type'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['tmp_name'] = $files ['multipleUpload'] ['tmp_name'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['error'] = $files ['multipleUpload'] ['error'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['multipleUpload'] ['size'] = $files ['multipleUpload'] ['size'] [$i];

            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($file_path));
            if(!($this->upload->do_upload('multipleUpload')) || $files ['multipleUpload'] ['error'] [$i] !=0)
            {
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->model('uploadModel','um');
                $this->um->insertRecord($user,$name);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('uploadForm');
    }
}

public function set_upload_options($file_path) {
    // upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config ['upload_path'] = $file_path;
    $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    return $config;
}
```

Comment: The following code uploads multiple files as well as creates a directory for each user and upload the files in that directory and the input element is as following  ===>    <input type="file" name="multipleUpload[]" multiple="multiple">

Answer (score 1):

```
private function upload_files($path, $title, $files)
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => $path,
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
        'overwrite'     => 1,
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
        $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

        $fileName = $title .'_'. $image;

        $images[] = $fileName;

        $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) {
            $this->upload->data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What different? Only return type is difference?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

if(isset($_FILES[$input_name]) && is_array($_FILES[$input_name]['name'])){
            $image_path = array();          
            $count = count($_FILES[$input_name]['name']);   
            for($key =0; $key <$count; $key++){     
                $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES[$input_name]['name'][$key]; 
                $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES[$input_name]['type'][$key]; 
                $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES[$input_name]['tmp_name'][$key]; 
                $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES[$input_name]['error'][$key]; 
                $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES[$input_name]['size'][$key]; 
                    
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES[$input_name]['name'][$key];                      
                $this->upload->initialize($config); 
                
                if($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $image_path[$key] = $path ."$data[file_name]";                  
                }else{
                    $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_error',"image upload! ".$error);
                }   
            }
            return json_encode($image_path);
        }
    
    
   ?>
```