# Save Image Name And Post Data Into Database

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a project where volunteers have to fill in registration form.

I want volunteers to be able to upload a profile image and save image name to database as well as the post data on the same form.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: where is you code and what you have tried for it?

Comment: you want upload and store in database??

Comment: store the name of the jpeg file in the data base and save the image to some location thats how its done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question is not clear ,

provide ,view ,controller as well.
anyways see this post it will help you.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter)

or

use `<?php echo form_open_multipart('yourcontroler/add');?>`
in your view file when dealing with image and text data.

in controller ,the best practice is to define two function one for image upload the other to validate ,and filter data.Like

```
             public function do_upload() {
                $path = '_assets/images/';
                $fileName = 'userpic.png';
                $config = array(
                    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|gif',
                    'upload_path' => $path,
                    'max_size' => '200',
                    'overwrite' => true,
                    'file_name' => $fileName,
                    'max_height' => "300",
                    'max_width' => "300",

                );

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('logo')) {
                    echo "error ";
                    die;
                } else {
                    $imageData = $this->upload->data();
                }

            }
```

and for data storing use simple function you usually do with form input.

Answer (score 4):

In the success part of upload form could do a if statement like below for update

**Update**

```
$user_info = $this->get_user();

if ($user_info) {

$image_info = $this->upload->data();

$data = array(
'username' => $user_info['username'],
'image' => $image_info['file_name']
);

// Only updates password if post value true
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
   $data = array(
      'password' => $this->input->post('password');
   );
}


$this->db->where('id', $user_info['id']);
$this->db->update('tablename', $data);

}
```

Else In the success part of upload form could do insert like below

**Insert**

```
$image_info = $this->upload->data();

$data = array(
   'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
   'password' => $this->input->post('password')
   'image' => $image_info['file_name']
);


$this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
```

**Upload Controller**

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '0'; // Unlimited
        $config['max_width']  = '0'; // Unlimited
        $config['max_height']  = '0'; // Unlimited

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $input_name = "userfile";

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($input_name))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {


            $user_info = $this->get_user();

            if ($user_info) {

                $image_info = $this->upload_data();

                $data = array(
                    'username' => $user_info['username'],
                    'image' => $image_info['file_name']
                );

                $this->db->where('id', $user_info['id']);
                $this->db->update('tablename', $data);

            }

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }

    public function get_user() {

        // your user model data

    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Upload library

Codeigniter 2 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html

Codeigniter 3 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I think (at least in codeigniter 3) ```this->upload_data()``` should be ```this->upload->data();```

Comment: @mheavers just a typo