# How to make Code Igniter Controller for multiple input form with type="file"

Tags: codeigniter

i want to ask, how to make the controller function in CodeIgniter for this view ?

```
    <form action="<?=base_url()?>posts/new_post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
     <input type="file" name="before" id="before" ><br>
     <input type="file" name="after" id="after" ><br>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter name"><br>
     <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter name"></textarea><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Profile Picture" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary  ">
    </form>
```

Thank You

Comment: are want to make form with codeigniter?

Comment: By searching google I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter