# How to send multiple file upload in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert data with multiple file, but the file is null if i insert to database. this is my code

FROM ACTION CODE

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>SystemCore/tambahKendaraan" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Foto Foto Kendaraan</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple="" required="" name="addKendaraanDinasFoto[]">
        <small>*Dapat Mencantumkan Foto Lebih Dari 1</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
    </form>
```

This i my Controller to upload data

```
    public function tambahKendaraan()
    {
        $simpanData = array(
            "id_jenis" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasJenis"),
            "plat_kendaraan" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasPlat"),
            "dinas_pengelola" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasPengelola"),
            "pemegang_kendaraan" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasPemegang"),
            "no_stnk" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasSTNK"),
            "no_rangka" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasRangka"),
            "masa_pajak" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasPajak"),
            "merk_kendaraan" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasMerk"),
            "warna_kendaraan" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasWarna"),
            "status_kendaraan" => $this->input->post("addKendaraanDinasStatus"),
        );
            if ($this->db->insert("tbl_mobil", $simpanData)) {

        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        date_default_timezone_get("Asia/Jakarta");

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $dataInfo = array();
        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['name']);

        for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
        {         
            $_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['name']= $files['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['type']= $files['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['tmp_name']= $files['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['error']= $files['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['size']= $files['addKendaraanDinasFoto']['size'][$i];

            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();

            $this->db->insert("tbl_fotomobil", $data);
        }


        foreach ($dataInfo as $infos) {
            $data = array(
                'id_mobil' => $insert_id,
                'tgl_foto' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'foto_mobil' => $infos['file_name'],
            );
        }

               $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<script>swal ( "Success" , "Data Kendaraan Berhasil Ditambahkan !" ,  "success" );</script>');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<script>swal ( "Error" ,  "Data Error !" ,  "error" );</script>');
            }
                redirect('kendaraan');
    }
    private function set_upload_options()
    {   
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path']   = './upload/kendaraan/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|svg';
        $config['max_size']      = 10097152;
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

        return $config;
    }
```

Result:

```
    array(3) {
      ["id_mobil"]=>
      int(0)
      ["tgl_foto"]=>
      string(19) "2019-07-09 09:55:58"
      ["foto_mobil"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    array(3) {
      ["id_mobil"]=>
      int(0)
      ["tgl_foto"]=>
      string(19) "2019-07-09 09:55:58"
      ["foto_mobil"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
```

Comment: take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138535/7499554

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple files upload in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Controller ::: 

   public function addmember()
      {

    if (empty($_FILES['user_image']['name']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_image', 'User Image', 'required');
    }
    if (empty($_FILES['user_gallery']['name']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_gallery[]', 'User Gallery', 'required');
    }

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

        $this->load->view('common_page/header');
        $this->load->view('common_page/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('form');
        $this->load->view('common_page/footer');
    }
    else
    {

        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('user_image') && !empty($_FILES['user_gallery']['name']))
        {
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadedFile = $uploadData['file_name'];

            $dataInfo = [];
            $files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['user_gallery']['name']);

            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {           
                $_FILES['user_gallery']['name']  = $files['user_gallery']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['user_gallery']['type']  = $files['user_gallery']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['user_gallery']['tmp_name'] = $files['user_gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['user_gallery']['error'] = $files['user_gallery']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['user_gallery']['size']  = $files['user_gallery']['size'][$i];    

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->upload->do_upload('user_gallery');
                $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
            }

            $all_imgs = '';

            if ( count($dataInfo) > 0) {

                foreach ($dataInfo as $info) {

                    $all_imgs .= $info['file_name'];
                    $all_imgs .= ',';
                }
            }

            $data = [
                'user_image' => $uploadedFile,
                'user_gallery' => $all_imgs
            ];

            $this->Admin_model->insertData($data,'member');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Member Register Successfully !!!');
            redirect('all/form');
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}


  VIEW :::
     <form role="form" id="member_form" action="<?php echo 
          base_url('all/addmember');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="box-body">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">User Image</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="user_image">
            <?php echo form_error('user_image', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">User Gallery Image</label>
            <input type="file" id="gallery" name="user_gallery[]" multiple="">
            <?php echo form_error('user_gallery', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
          </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
         </div>
       </form>
```