# I am getting only first image in an array while uploading file, I want all images in array.Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

Here I am attaching the code of the desires problem.
Cotroller has following code.
Controller=>

```
//Load upload library
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $images = array();
            $i = 0;                                                                 
            foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) 
            {                                                                
                $tmp = explode(".",$value['name'][$i]);                
                $imagename = time().".".end($tmp); 

                $_FILES['file']['name']     = $imagename;
                $_FILES['file']['type']     = $value['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['error']    = $value['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['size']     = $value['size'][$i];

                $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['file_name']     = $imagename;                                

                $this->upload->initialize($config);                                        

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
                {
                    $error = array($i => $this->upload->display_errors());                 
                    echo "<pre>";print_r($error);die;
                }            
                else 
                { 
                    array_push($images,$this->upload->data()['file_name']);                 
                }        
                $i++;                
            }            
            echo "<pre>";print_r($images);die;
```

This is a form code that I am using while uploading file.
View =>

```
<?php $attributes = array(
 "class"                 => "form-horizontal m-t-20",
 "method"                => "post",
 "novalidate"            => "",
 "enctype"               => "multipart/form-data"
);
echo form_open('admin/user/adduser', $attributes); ?>
```

Here is my file input control.

```
<label for="file">Profile Images*</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple required placeholder="Profile Images" class="form-control">
```

Comment: What about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60917790/12731030) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload multiple images using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317418/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting empty array, I need array of image while uploading multiple images in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917320/i-am-getting-empty-array-i-need-array-of-image-while-uploading-multiple-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$value) {
```

and change `$i` to the `$key` as follows (apply to the all)

```
$_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES["files"]['type'][$key];
```

As wazabii suggested, attached some random string to the file name. You can use `rand(100,10000)`

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Are you sure ? Because while I am passing tmp_name it will consider only tmp_name in loop.

Comment: Yes, it only consider `tmp_name` when looping. But, In order to grab data, you should use `$_FILES["files"]['type'][$key]`. Try `print_r()`, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the time() will be the same on all the images, so the file name is not unique. This is easily fixed by adding the array key to the file name.

```
$tmp = explode(".",$value['name'][$i]);
$imagename = time()."-".$key.".".end($tmp);
```

Comment: Not usefull, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

contoller code

```
public function upload_multiple($field_name,$path){

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);//count for number of image files
    $image_name =array();
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES[$field_name]['name']= $files[$field_name]['name'][$i];
        $_FILES[$field_name]['type']= $files[$field_name]['type'][$i];
        $_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name'] = $files[$field_name]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES[$field_name]['error']= $files[$field_name]['error'][$i]; 
        $_FILES[$field_name]['size'] = $files[$field_name]['size'][$i];
    
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($path));//for initalizing configuration for each image
        $this->upload->do_upload($field_name);  

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $image_name[]=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];//store file name to store in database
    }
    return $image_name;//all images name which is uploaded
}
public function set_upload_options($path)
{   
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

function call

```
  $image_name=$this->upload_multiple('portfolio_image',$path);//for multiple image upload
```

input field

```
 <input type="file" id="portfolio_image" name="protfolio_image[]" >
```