# Upload Multiple Images and Generate Large Size

Tags: image, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have already generated a code that will upload multiple images in codeigniter, however I can't generate a large size of the uploaded images to other directory using codeigniter image library.

Using the codes below, it will only generate one image even though if the user uploaded multiple images.

```
  function insert_prod(){   

    $foldername = $_POST['folder'];
    $path = './uploads/products/'.$foldername;

    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    mkdir($path.'/zoomimages', 0777, true);

    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){

        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $config['file_name'] = 'img_'.$i;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();

        $upload_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $full_path = $upload_data['upload_data']['full_path'];
        $u_data = $upload_data['upload_data'];
        // var_dump( $this->upload->data());
        // var_dump($upload_data); 
        echo $cpt;
        $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config1['source_image']    = $full_path;
        $config1['new_image'] =$path.'/zoomimages';
        $config1['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config1['width']    = 300;
        $config1['height']  = 300;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: For every upload specify the input name `$this->upload->do_upload('NAME');`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0

Comment: I am using that codes. I am able to upload multiple images but I want to generate a large size for the images and put it on other directory.

Comment: Ok i got you, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are loading library with `$this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);` inside your loop so codeigniter see the class is already load so its not setting your `$config1 again`

Move   `$this->load->library('image_lib');` out side your loop

Then add `$this->image_lib->initialize($config1);` instant of `$this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);`