# how to upload multiple images on codeigniter from single input fileds

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to upload multiple images on my gallery 
 till today I was using  this code to upload single images

my controller is

```
public function addPhoto($album_id)
        {
            if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('caption', 'Caption', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Image', 'callback__checkImage');

                if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                    $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('upload_path');
                    $config['allowed_types'] = $this->config->item('allowed_types');
                    $config['max_size'] = $this->config->item('max_size');
                    $config['max_width'] = $this->config->item('max_width');
                    $config['max_height'] = $this->config->item('max_height');
                    $config['encrypt_name'] = $this->config->item('encrypt_name');

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                        $image = $this->upload->data();

                        $this->album_model->addPhoto($image['file_name'], $album_id);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Photo added successfully.');
                        redirect('album/photos/'.$album_id);
                    } else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
                        redirect('album/addPhoto/'.$album_id);
                    }
                }
            }

            $data['title'] = 'Add Photo';
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('album/add_photo', '', true);
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
```

My models is

```
function addPhoto($image, $album_id)
    {
        $this->db->set('name', $image);
        $this->db->set('caption', $this->input->post('caption'));
        $this->db->set('album_id', $album_id);
        $this->db->insert('photos');
    }
```

and my view is

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Add Photo</h1>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>

    <div>
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="userfile">
        <?php echo form_error('userfile'); ?>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div>
        <label>Caption</label>
        <input type="text" name="caption" value="<?php echo set_value('caption'); ?>" placeholder="Caption">
        <?php echo form_error('caption'); ?>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div>
        <label></label>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what I'm using for uploading single images now I want to upload multiple and I had only one images fields on database did I need to make more images fields for upload multiple images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to send `<input type="file" name="userfile">`
as an array like so:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="userfile[]">
```

Then for each posted image do an upload.

BTW a quick search on this site gave me this post, that has all other info you need: 
[Multiple files upload (Array) with CodeIgniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload multiple images there are so many plugins for that

> [Blueimp](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

This a very simple and very great plugin I have also used it in may projects.

Comment: Yes but you have to code for that it will send all uploaded files detail to your action.