# Unable to upload files when using two file controls in form - PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having issues in uploading files using PHP. The files are hosted on AWS. My form looks like this:

```
<form name="hello" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <label>Audio file</label>
        <input type="file" name="audio_file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />  
</form>
```

When i submit this form nothing happens the page keeps on loading. I tried by removing one file control and it worked fine i.e one file was uploaded successfully. If i submit only one file then it works fine but not when there are two different file controls.

PHP ini settings looks like this:

```
max_file_uploads 10
memory_limit 1024M
upload_max_filesize 32M
post_max_size 32M
```

Not sure what's the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Your action is blank, is the page with the form the same as the URL where the upload will be processed? Remember, when you upload a file, it will wait for the browser to send the file **before** running the script, so if it's a large file you'll need to wait a while.

Comment: Yes form action is same as the page url. File size < 1 MB. This form works only with one file control. If i upload only a picture then it will upload just fine. But if i try to upload two different files using two file controls it doesn't.

Comment: can you post php code?

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter's upload library for uploading the files. I tried with one file and it was uploaded successfully. So there is nothing wrong with the upload library. I even tried with core PHP code and the result was same. When i print the content of $_FILES array it shows correctly in case of one file. But when i use two file controls to upload two different files it doesn't work. The page keeps on loading. I checked the error logs as well but no errors.

Comment: $filea = $_FILES['filea'];
$fileb = $_FILES['fileb'];
move_uploaded_file($filea['tmp_name'], '/destination/'.$filea['name']);move_uploaded_file($fileb['tmp_name'], '/destination/'.$fileb['name']);

Comment: Yes i've tried this as well. But the page just keeps on loading. It works only when there is one file control in the form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524356/multiple-files-upload-array-with-codeigniter-2-0 try this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But did you read my question? I don't want to upload multiple files using one file control. I want to upload two files using two file controls in the form.

Comment: Sorry i dont know about Codeigniter. Am learning Codeigniter.

Comment: No need to apologize. It has nothing to do with codeigniter. Its a simple upload functionality and it should work fine. Don't know if its a server issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with our internal network (static IP).