# How to upload files using Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use this strange code to upload files:

```
        if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['name'])) > 0) {
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

                /* File upload configuration */
                $uploadPath = 'uploads/reviews/';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                /* $config['max_size']    = '100'; */
                /* $config['max_width'] = '1024'; */
                /* $config['max_height'] = '768'; */

                /* Load and initialize upload library */
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                /* Upload file to server */
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    /* Uploaded file data */
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                    $uploadData[$i]['uploaded_on'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
```

But I wonder why it rewrites a `$_FILES` and why I get error on line:

```
    `$_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];`
```

Error is:

```
Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type int
```

Comment: why do you use *this strange code*, write the code new by following the [file upload class tutorial](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html). In your example you do in each loop an overwrite the $_FILES array, load and initialize the library over and over again? that code is just wrong and needs to be re-written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're looping over an array and modifying that same array within the loop.

`$_FILES['file']['error'][$i]` is an integer, so in the first iteration of the loop `$_FILES['file']['error']` becomes an integer.

In the second iteration of the loop, when you try to access `$_FILES['file']['error'][$i]`, it is trying to treat the integer that is now at `$_FILES['file']['error']` as an array and get element `[$i]`, which is impossible.

(You're not getting this error on `$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]`, `$_FILES['file']['type'][$i]` and `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]` because the file `name`, `type` and `tmp_name` are string values.

And when you try to treat a string value as an array, it will get the character at position `[$i]`. Which probably isn't what you were looking for either, but it does not give an error.)

The solution is to copy the `$_FILES` array and loop over the copy while assigning the values back to the `$_FILES` array, as in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11539061/3960296