# uploading images in codeigniter, is userfile required?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using the function below to upload my image files to my server(Localhost). It is fine and image is being uploaded. But I need two image fields and hence both the images should be uploaded once the submit button is clicked. I used the function described here **[Codeigniter multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276756/codeigniter-multiple-file-upload)** , but it is not working.

I get this error message

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 161
```

Well I cannot understand where the error is.
The function that I am using to upload single image is

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
           //failed display the errors
        }
        else
        {
            //success

        }
    }
```

In addition I also like to ask can i change the input field name of my choice. i.e i always need to implement `<input type="file" name="userfile"/>` . Is it possible to change the name? I tried changing it and I get the message **No file was selected**, so that must mean that I cannot change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to loop through the uploaded files like it is shown in your provided link.

```
function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {

            if (!empty($value['tmp_name'])) {

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    //failed display the errors
                } else {
                    //success
                }

            }
        }
}
```

And try using HTML like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file_1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file_2" />
<input type="file" name="file3" id="file_3" />
```

You can change the names of the input fields as you like.

Comment: I still get that error message that I have posted in the question.

Comment: It is only uploading one image

Comment: Have you replaced `//failed display the errors` and `//success` with code? If yes then what is there.

Comment: ya.. I was using redirect .. my bad .. sorry.. it worked.. thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you want to call initialize() inside the loop, unless you intend to change that per image file

Comment: @M.Rabe I want change all file names . how can i change? i  only get original file names

Answer (score 0):

If you are using file multi-select, then do this:

HTML (HTML5 file input with array name allows to select multiple files):

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"/>
```

or

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"/>
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"/>
```

PHP in CodeIgniter:

```
// load upload library (put your own settings there)
$this->load->library('upload', array('allowed_types' => 'svg|gif|jpg|png', 'upload_path' => $GLOBALS['config']['upload_path'], ));

// normalise files array
$input_name = 'userfile'; // change it when needed to match your html
$field_names = array('name', 'type', 'tmp_name', 'error', 'size', );
$keys = array();
foreach($field_names as $field_name){
    if (isset($_FILES[$input_name][$field_name])) foreach($_FILES[$input_name][$field_name] as $key => $value){
        $_FILES[$input_name.'_'.$key][$field_name] = $value;
        $keys[$key] = $key;
    }
}
unset($_FILES[$input_name]); // just in case

foreach ($keys as $key){

    $new_file = $this->upload->do_upload($input_name.'_'.$key);

    // do your stuff with each uploaded file here, delete for example:
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    unlink($upload_data['file_name']);

}
```