# Add upload image field to register form using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add an upload image field to register a form in [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter).

My register code in the controller:

```
function add_new_ticket() {

    if ($this->input->post('fullname', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('nID', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('age', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('gender', TRUE)
        // && $this->input->post('isFileID', TRUE)
        // && $this->input->post('FileID', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('phone', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('type', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('opsType', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('clienc', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('dr', TRUE)
        && strlen($this->input->post('phone', TRUE)) >= 9
        && strlen($this->input->post('nID', TRUE)) >= 9
        && (int) $this->input->post('age', TRUE) <= 99
        && count(explode('-',$this->input->post('default-date', TRUE)) > 1)
    ){
```

Also my code in the model file:

```
<?php
    class user extends CI_Model {

        public function add() {
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'add_date' => time(),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'birth_date' => $this->input->post('birth'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                'sex' => $this->input->post('type'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'main_street' => $this->input->post('main_street'),
                'sub_street' => $this->input->post('sub_street'),
                'type' => $this->input->post('member_type'),
                'delegate_name' => $this->input->post('delegate_name'),
                'delegate_email' => $this->input->post('delegate_email'),
                'delegate_pass' => md5($this->input->post('delegate_pass')),
                'location' => serialize(array($this->input->post('lat'), $this->input->post('lng')))
            );
            $this->db->insert('admins', $data);
        }

        public function edit($id = FALSE) {

            $this->db->set('name', $this->input->post('name'));

            $this->db->set('email', $this->input->post('email'));
            $this->db->set('phone', $this->input->post('phone'));
            $this->db->set('mobile', $this->input->post('mobile'));
            $this->db->set('birth_date', $this->input->post('birth'));

            $this->db->set('first_name', $this->input->post('first_name'));
            $this->db->set('last_name', $this->input->post('last_name'));

            $this->db->set('city', $this->input->post('city'));

            $this->db->set('main_street', $this->input->post('main_street'));

            $this->db->set('sub_street', $this->input->post('sub_street'));

            if ($this->input->post('type')) {
                $this->db->set('sex', $this->input->post('type'));
            }

            if ($this->input->post('lat') and $this->input->post('lng')) {
                $this->db->set('location', serialize(array($this->input->post('lat'), $this->input->post('lng'))));
            }

            if ($this->input->post('password') !== '') {
                $this->db->set('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            }

            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('admins');
        }

        public function del($id = FALSE) {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('admins');
        }
    }
```

I want to add a field that allows to upload images.

Comment: Have you looked at codeigniter file upload http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: yes and i make it but you dont understand me i want to insert this option into regster form

Comment: what actually you want did you want to know how to upload image??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to add "image upload" option in form

```
public function add() {



/* Configuration array various settings

  can be set here

  **/
 $config['upload_path'] = '/file_path/'; // path where image will be saved
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->upload->do_upload('image');
         $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

         $image = $data_upload_files[full_path];
$data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'add_date' => time(),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'birth_date' => $this->input->post('birth'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
        'sex' => $this->input->post('type'),
        'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'main_street' => $this->input->post('main_street'),
        'sub_street' => $this->input->post('sub_street'),
        'type' => $this->input->post('member_type'),
        'delegate_name' => $this->input->post('delegate_name'),
        'delegate_email' => $this->input->post('delegate_email'),
        'delegate_pass' => md5($this->input->post('delegate_pass')),
        'location' => serialize(array($this->input->post('lat'), $this->input->post('lng')))
        'image'=>$image; // add this for image

    );
 $this->db->insert('admins', $data);

}
```

View has something like this

```
<input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
```

Controller

```
function add_new_ticket() {

    if ($this->input->post('fullname', TRUE) 
        && $this->input->post('nID', TRUE) 
        && $this->input->post('age', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('gender', TRUE) 
        // && $this->input->post('isFileID', TRUE)
        // && $this->input->post('FileID', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('phone', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('type', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('opsType', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('clienc', TRUE)
        && $this->input->post('dr', TRUE)
        && strlen($this->input->post('phone', TRUE)) >= 9
        && strlen($this->input->post('nID', TRUE)) >= 9
        && (int) $this->input->post('age', TRUE) <= 99
        && $this->upload->do_upload() // add something like this              
&& count(explode('-',$this->input->post('default-date', TRUE)) > 1)
            ){
```

**NOTE:**

Input name must be be defined as same in $this->upload->do_upload('image'); i.e. name="image"

Input element must have multiple="multiple" or just multiple

3.$this->load->library('upload'); //to load library

4.The callback, $this->upload->do_upload() will upload the file selected in the given field name to the destination folder.

5.And the callback $this->upload->data() returns an array of data related to the uploaded file like the file name, path, size etc.

Comment: thx you for helping me but i want you to explain mor breifly becasue i dont understand   , which code should i put in (  controllers , modles, view ) folders

Comment: hellow i try to do this but no image uploades is there any modification in my sql database such as add tables or make any thing

Comment: i dont see any error but i cant see images in the directory " uploads" although i make 777 permission

Comment: @ahmed add `die(var_dump($data));` before  `$this->db->insert('admins', $data);` in your model and show the results

Comment: i do this but when i filled all information  and then press the button it seems freeze  nothing change

Comment: @ahmed does it shows anything on screen long array results

Comment: nothing " can i attach you the files to see whats wrong

Comment: thx you for helping me i attach you the application files i upload it into my site  the url    http://alkhaldiyah.com/tm/application.zip

Comment: @ahmed your code it has thousands of mistake i suggest you to debug the code and turn on error repporting ON and various error getting techinques

Comment: @ahmed see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages to see the errors on screen then errors will guide you rest

Comment: the code is working can you edit the " Controller , model, "  for me

Comment: @ahmed sorry but this cannot be done against SO this something you has be done by you,this is how you learn.read the link i suggested then you can do it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

make an if statement when uploading bro

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
            {

                $profile = array(
                    'emp_code' => $this->input->post('emp_code'), 
                    'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'), 
                    'mname' => $this->input->post('mname'), 
                    'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                    'dob' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('dob'))),
                    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'emp_status' => $this->input->post('emp_status'),
                    'position' => $this->input->post('position'),
                    'dep_id' => $this->input->post('dep_id'),
                    'payroll_num' => $this->input->post('pay_num'),
                    'tax_code_id' => $this->input->post('tax_code'), 
                    'tax_id' => $this->input->post('tax_id'), 
                    'date_joined' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('doj'))),
                    'sss_num' => $this->input->post('sss_num'),
                    'PhilHealth_num' => $this->input->post('PhilHealth_num'),
                    'pagibig_num' => $this->input->post('pagibig_num'),
                    'image'=> $info['file_name']
                    );
                $id = $this->accounts->insert_employee($profile);
//insert with image
                $sched = array(
                    'Monday'=>$v1,
                    'Tuesday'=>$v2,
                    'Wednesday'=>$v3,
                    'Thursday'=>$v4,
                    'Friday'=>$v5,
                    'Saturday'=>$v6,
                    'Sunday'=>$v7,
                    'date_From'=>$this->input->post('from'),
                    'date_to'=>$this->input->post('to'),
                    'emp_id'=> $id

                    );
                $this->accounts->insert_emp_sched($sched);
                redirect('account/view_all_employee');



            }else if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
            {

                $profile = array(
                    'emp_code' => $this->input->post('emp_code'), 
                    'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'), 
                    'mname' => $this->input->post('mname'), 
                    'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                    'dob' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('dob'))),
                    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'emp_status' => $this->input->post('emp_status'),
                    'position' => $this->input->post('position'),
                    'dep_id' => $this->input->post('dep_id'),
                    'payroll_num' => $this->input->post('pay_num'),
                    'tax_code_id' => $this->input->post('tax_code'), 
                    'tax_id' => $this->input->post('tax_id'), 
                    'date_joined' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('doj'))),
                    'sss_num' => $this->input->post('sss_num'),
                    'PhilHealth_num' => $this->input->post('PhilHealth_num'),
                    'pagibig_num' => $this->input->post('pagibig_num'),
                    );
                $id = $this->accounts->insert_employee($profile);
//insert without image
                $sched = array(
                    'Monday'=>$v1,
                    'Tuesday'=>$v2,
                    'Wednesday'=>$v3,
                    'Thursday'=>$v4,
                    'Friday'=>$v5,
                    'Saturday'=>$v6,
                    'Sunday'=>$v7,
                    'date_From'=>$this->input->post('from'),
                    'date_to'=>$this->input->post('to'),
                    'emp_id'=> $id

                    );
                $this->accounts->insert_emp_sched($sched);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('item','The Newly added Employee Dose\'nt have a Profile Pic <a href="view_employee/'.$id.'">View The User</a>');
                redirect('account/view_all_employee');
            }else{
                $data['emp_status'] =  array('Part-Time' => 'Part-Time','Regular' => 'Regular', 'Probationary' => 'Probationary' );
                $data['gender'] = array('male' => 'Male','female'=>'Female' );
                $this->load->view('employee/create',$data); //error in form validation
            }
```