# How to get the name of userfiles in controller to add to database

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

This is the code so far.
I have 2 images that are getting uploaded and added to the desired map.
My question is, how do i get both names from the images so I can add just the names to the database together with my other form information.

public function CreateTypesForGamma() {

```
        $type              = new stdClass();

        $type->TypeID     = $this->input->post('typeID') == 0 ? null : $this->input->post('typeID');
        $type->Titel        = $this->input->post('titel');
        $type->TechnischeFiche      = $this->input->post('technischeFiche');
        $type->GammaID      = $this->input->post('gammaID');
        $type->ExtLink      = $this->input->post('extLink');
        $type->InfoNL       = $this->input->post('infoNL');
        $type->InfoFR       = $this->input->post('infoFR');
        $type->InfoEN       = $this->input->post('infoEN');

        $files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
             for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            if ($i == 0)
             $images[] = $fileName;
            }
              $fileName = implode(',',$images);
              $this->gamma_model->upload_image($fileName);
            system.out.println($images);
        if ($type->TypeID == 0) {
            $type->TypeID = $this->type_model->insert($type);
        } else {
            $this->type_model->update($type);
        }
        redirect('gamma/viewAdminGamma');

}
private function set_upload_options()
    { 
      // upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'images/types'; //give the path to upload the image in folder
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5120';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        return $config;
    }
```

Comment: The desired column names are $type->TypeFoto  and $type->Lastentabel

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: what do you get result of  `var_dump($fileName);` this  $fileName must contain name of images

Comment: the var dump gives: string(16) "catmanbatman.png"  aka just the first name, not the second one

Comment: @Ricky, I have seen this example alredy, but it just pushes an array to the database with : $this->db->insert('uploaded_files', $file_data); instead of the entire form I want to push

Comment: @SdR for pushing all the thing in database at once you have to collect all data in array and then push that array in DB as `$this->db->insert('table', $data);`

Comment: @SdR first get the ID of the form you are saving in another table and insert that ID in the file upload table while you are inserting the image in loop and get the images based on the ID

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 Alredy taken care of:  if ($type->TypeID == 0) {
            $type->TypeID = $this->type_model->insert($type);
        } else {
            $this->type_model->update($type);
        }
I just need to get $Type->TypeFoto and $Type->Lastentabel the names of the pictures

Comment: @Ricky , that's kind of my backup plan. I'd like to try and get it done like this first

Comment: then try putting `$type->TypeFoto=$fileName[0]` this gives name of first image and  `$type->Lastentabel =$fileName[1];` name of second image

Comment: Got it! if u look at the code u see:   if ($i == 0){
             $images[] = $fileName;} if you remove that images gets 2 values, name 1 and name 2. works perfect now. thx for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to  following

```
 $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
             for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

             $images[] = $fileName;
             $type->TypeFoto=$fileName[0];// this gives name of first            
             image 
             $type->Lastentabel =$fileName[1];
            }
              $fileName = implode(',',$images);
              $this->gamma_model->upload_image($fileName);
            system.out.println($images);
        if ($type->TypeID == 0) {
            $type->TypeID = $this->type_model->insert($type);
        } else {
            $this->type_model->update($type);
        }
        redirect('gamma/viewAdminGamma');

}
private function set_upload_options()
    { 
      // upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'images/types'; //give the path to upload the image in folder
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5120';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        return $config;
    }
```