# Codeigniter file uploading error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to upload multiple images using codeigniter file uploading library. Everything is working except it's not saving the images in directory,
I have check permissions everything is perfect. I have also tried changing package but still face same issue.

This is my code for uploading.

```
   $count = count($_FILES['upload_' . $increment]['size']);

   for ($s = 0; $s <= $count-1; $s++) {
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
     $config['max_size']      = '10000';
     $config['max_width']     = '2048';
     $config['max_height']    = '1152';

     $image = $config['file_name'] = $c_id . '-' . $s . '.jpg';

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);
     $this->upload->do_upload();

     $data = $this->upload->data();
     $data = array('c_id' => $c_id, 'image'=> $image);

     $this->db->insert('images', $data);
   }

   $increment++;
```

Comment: Maybe this will work `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';`

Comment: i have uploads folder in the parent directory

Comment: OK than remove the dot from path

Comment: already tried that.

Comment: Plz find the upload errors. $this->upload->display_errors()

Comment: nothing in errors

Comment: Where u define $c_id

Comment: it is the insert id of previous insertion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload multiple images with codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017753/upload-multiple-images-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using html form action for submit the data?

If yes, please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into your form tag as:

```
<form action="your action url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[Downlaod this Codeigniter Library and put this file under application/libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6fcnoegg5v8vit/MY_Upload.php?dl=0)

Controller

```
if ($_FILES) {
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '200';
    $config['max_width']     = '1024';
    $config['max_height']    = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload("file")) {
        $data['errors'] = ($this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        $images = ($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
        $this->user_model->addUserImage($images[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
public function addUserImage($image)
{
  $image_data=array(
    'name'=>$image['file_name']
  );
   $this->db->insert('user_images',$image_data);
   return true;
}
```

Let me if any query here