# submitting multiple files thru a form with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have the following:

```
<form id="set" method="post" action="<?php echo $base_url; ?>schedule" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
?>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="selective_file">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $name[$i]; ?>" style="display:none;"/>
<?php
     }
?>
   <input type="submit" value="Post />
</form>
```

The client has to submit 10 photos and once they click the button and the form is submitted, the `schedule` controller gets the files as follows

```
public function index() {   
    $files = $this->input->post('files');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');

    print_r($files);
    print_r($name);
}
```

I know that for uploading files in CI, the following has always worked for me

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {    
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
   print_r($error);
} else {
    $pic = $this->upload->data();
    }
```

How do I identify the files with CI so that it can be uploaded successfully while looping thru the array of files with the correct corresponding name from the checkbox field?

Comment: You have a typo either in your PHP or HTML. Is it `file` or `files`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this SO question, the users question code is relevant to your scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908247/codeigniter-multiple-file-upload